# Specify Animation sprites size in world units ALL AT ONCE

Tags: java, libgdx, game-engine

If I use sprites I can setup thie size and position of the sprite with reference to my game WORLD UNITS:

```
    AtlasRegion region = textureAtlas.findRegion("0001");
    sprite = new Sprite(region);
    sprite.setPosition(11.5f, 5f);
    sprite.setSize(7f, 7f * region.getRegionHeight() / region.getRegionWidth());
```

How can I achieve that with an Animation. How can I set the size of each keyframe sprite?

```
textureAtlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("data/bycicle.atlas"));

TextureRegion[] rotateUpFrames = new TextureRegion[4];

// Create an array of TextureRegions
rotateUpFrames[0] = (textureAtlas.findRegion("0001"));
rotateUpFrames[1] = (textureAtlas.findRegion("0002"));
rotateUpFrames[2] = (textureAtlas.findRegion("0003"));
rotateUpFrames[3] = (textureAtlas.findRegion("0004"));

rotateUpAnimation = new Animation(0.1f,rotateUpFrames);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set up an Animation subclass so I can have convenience methods to apply the scale each time the sprite is updated with a new region. For example:

```
public class AnimationPlus extends Animation {

    float scale;

    public AnimationPlus (float frameDuration, 
            Array<? extends TextureRegion> keyFrames, PlayMode playMode, float scale) 
    {
        super(frameDuration, keyFrames, playMode);
        this.scale = scale;
    }

    public void applyKeyFrameToSprite (float stateTime, Sprite sprite)
    {
        TextureRegion region = getKeyFrame(stateTime);
        sprite.setSize(scale, 
            scale * region.getRegionHeight() / region.getRegionWidth());
    }
}
```

By the way, if you name your frames of animation with underscore number suffixes (such as "bike_0", "bike_1", "bike_2", etc), then you can conveniently get the array of regions like this:

```
Array<TextureRegion> bikeRegions = textureAtlas.findRegions("bike");
AnimationPlus animation = new AnimationPlus(0.1f, bikeRegions, PlayMode.LOOP, 7f);
```